# Issues with encoding when using an Rscript through launchd

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, launchd

I encountered an unexpected issue when trying to schedule a R script with `launchd`: using the Rgui or Rscript in the terminal (Mac OS X 10.7.5), the script has no issue running, but when the script is run using launchd it seems to have an encoding issue.

As an example this script to create a wordcloud from the RSS feed of the journal Le Monde:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
require(wordcloud)
require(tm)
require(XML)
titles <- xpathSApply(htmlParse("http://www.lemonde.fr/rss/une.xml"),"//item/title",xmlValue)
titles <- gsub("[[:punct:]]"," ",titles)
rss <- Corpus(VectorSource(titles),readerControl=list(language="fr"))
rss <- tm_map(rss, stripWhitespace)
rss <- tm_map(rss, function(x)removeWords(x,stopwords("fr")))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(rss)
m <- as.matrix(tdm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
png("/path/to/wordcloud.png",w=5,h=5,units="in",res=100)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
wordcloud(d$word,d$freq,scale=c(3,.1),min.freq=2)
dev.off()
```

After being given the permissions using `chmod +x`, if I run the script through Rgui or through the terminal I get something like this:

[image]

But if I create a LaunchAgent to schedule this script to be run at a given time interval with a plist file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>test</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>/path/to/test.R</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And then load it and kickstart it:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist
launchctl start test
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

So I guess my questions are:
- Why is that?
- How to get around that?

**Edit**
After @hrbrmstr comment, I inserted the line `writeLines(capture.output(Sys.getenv()), con="/tmp/launchenv.txt")` inside the code.
The main difference between the contents of `Sys.getenv()` is that the one corresponding to the Rgui contained different `R_PLATFORM` from the two others, and `R_LIBS` while the two other had a `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES`.
The only thing in common to the Rgui and the terminal but different in the output from launchd is that the PATH contained `/usr/local/bin` (which is a folder that doesn't exist on my computer, as a matter of fact) on top of everything else. 
I tried nonetheless to run the script while adding these two lines in the code:

```
Sys.setenv(LANG='en') #language of my GUI, just in case
Sys.setenv(PATH='/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin')
```

but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Have you tried other encoding values in the ?xml tag of your LaunchAgent? Or just tried removing `encoding="UTF-8"`? Most likely, it is interacting with the XML package.

Comment: The `htmlParse` also has an encoding argument, I would try to play with that.

Comment: Given how thorough your post was, I felt compelled to try to duplicate on my Mac (OS X Mavericks, R 3.1.1). I duplicated everything and the launchd wordcloud is fine. Try adding `writeLines(capture.output(Sys.getenv()), con="/tmp/launchenv.txt")` to the script and see if there's any significant differences in environment variables between your interactive session and what is being setup with launchd.

Comment: @flodel I got rid of the `encoding` part in the plist file but got the same result.

Comment: @flodel I tried adding `encoding="UTF-8"` to `htmlParse` with no result. But the doc of `htmlParse` says anyhow that `If the XML/HTML document does specify its own encoding that value is used regardless of any value specified by the caller.` and this rss feed starts with `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally solved this issue while bumping into it in a different situation.

Consider this code, similar to the one in the question, with the difference that the output is a text file:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
require(wordcloud)
require(tm)
require(XML)
titles <- xpathSApply(htmlParse("http://www.lemonde.fr/rss/une.xml"),"//item/title",xmlValue)
titles <- gsub("[[:punct:]]"," ",titles)
rss <- Corpus(VectorSource(titles),readerControl=list(language="fr"))
rss <- tm_map(rss, stripWhitespace)
rss <- tm_map(rss, function(x)removeWords(x,stopwords("fr")))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(rss)
m <- as.matrix(tdm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
sink("test.txt")
for(i in d$word) cat(i,"\n")
sink()
```

I now work on Mac OSX 10.10 and now the issue presented in the question happens also when launching the script through the terminal and not just with launchd. The resulting `test.txt` file in both case contains:

```
contre 
crise 
des 
2015 
2<U+00A0>milliards 
<U+00A0>centre 
<U+00AB><U+00A0>il 
<U+00AB><U+00A0>jungle<U+00A0><U+00BB> 
<U+00E9>limin<U+00E9>s 
<U+00E9>lus 
<U+2019>attaque 
<U+2019>etat 
<U+2019>europe 
<U+2019>euros 
<U+2019>opposition 
<U+2019>union 
acc<U+00E9>l<U+00E8>re 
...
```

The issue is not, I believe, with the encoding during input but actually with the encoding during output. Here `sink` uses the default encoding of the session.

```
> getOption("encoding")
[1] "native.enc"
```

The so-called 'native.enc' is given by `Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")` as per [this comment by Brian Ripley](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-August/320677.html).

When in the RGUI, my default encoding is:

```
> Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")
[1] "en_US.UTF-8"
```

While the default encoding in the Rscript environment is:

```
$ Rscript -e 'Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")'
[1] "C"
```

Hence the following (hacky) solution for the code in the question:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
require(wordcloud)
require(tm)
require(XML)
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_US.UTF-8") # <- Here
titles <- xpathSApply(htmlParse("http://www.lemonde.fr/rss/une.xml"),"//item/title",xmlValue)
titles <- gsub("[[:punct:]]"," ",titles)
rss <- Corpus(VectorSource(titles),readerControl=list(language="fr"))
rss <- tm_map(rss, stripWhitespace)
rss <- tm_map(rss, function(x)removeWords(x,stopwords("fr")))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(rss)
m <- as.matrix(tdm)
v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
png("/path/to/wordcloud.png",w=5,h=5,units="in",res=100)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
wordcloud(d$word,d$freq,scale=c(3,.1),min.freq=2)
dev.off()
```